# Getting data between values and greater than

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
        Dictionary<char, ValuePair> dictionary = new Dictionary<char, ValuePair>();
```

With the following struct:

```
struct ValuePair
{
    public double Value1;
    public double Value2;
}
```

With the following values:

```
        dictionary.Add('A', new ValuePair { Value1 = 0.0, Value2 = 1.0 });
        dictionary.Add('B', new ValuePair { Value1 = 1.0, Value2 = 1.2 });
        dictionary.Add('C', new ValuePair { Value1 = 1.2, Value2 = 1.4 });
        dictionary.Add('D', new ValuePair { Value1 = 1.4, Value2 = 1.6 });

        dictionary.Add('E', new ValuePair { Value1 = 1.6, Value2 = 1.8 });
        dictionary.Add('F', new ValuePair { Value1 = 1.8, Value2 = 2.0 });
        dictionary.Add('G', new ValuePair { Value1 = 2.0, Value2 = double.MaxValue });
```

With query syntax I'm checking if a value is between one of the values, or if the case is G it justneed to be greater than 2.0. I don't like the solution with double.MaxValue. Is there any other way?

```
        var getValue = (from d in dictionary
                       where 2.1 >= d.Value.Value1 && 2.1 < d.Value.Value2 
                       select d.Key).FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(getValue);
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly don't you like about the `double.MaxValue` solution? It seems to be clear what the max value for selecting is.

Comment: It seems wierd in a exams project where the values is very small to use a number so big as double.MaxValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nullable values, keeping in mind that any type of comparison between null and not-null will return false.

If you make Value2 nullable, your condition will transform to something like:

```
2.1 >= d.Value.Value1 && !(2.1 >= d.Value.Value2)
```